# Mixed DML causing test classes to fail to to Process builder

Tags: apex, unit-test, process-builder, failing-tests, mixed-dml

I have a Test class which was working fine but after a new process builder was created on user object to update a custom field created on user object, it started failing. In my test class code I am inserting the account, contact and then a user related to that contact, the test is throwing Mixed DML error. 
I understand that this is because I cant do DML on both setup and non-setup in single transaction,so used Test.startTest and Test.stopTest and within it I inserted the user but it didn't work.  For the second option ,i.e, User of System.runAs(user), I cant do this as this "user" is what I am inserting . How to deal and resolve this?

Comment: you can try this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects_test_methods.htm

Comment: I have gone through this guide page. But my main issue here is that if I create another future method to create and insert the user, then I need few details from inserted contact which will be present in another testmethod. Secondly, I will have to get the return the user created to another methods for assertion which is also not possible since future method is of void type.

Comment: why will you need to return anything just query the data since its already inserted

Comment: Yes but I need to run my methods using that user in user context . So I need to call other methods using System.Runas and if I am doing that in the same future method then none of the called method is getting covered . This may be due to this method being future and not test.

Comment: You can do `System.runAs(<existing sysadmin account>)`

Comment: Yes admin is already having access to all objects , then it will be of no use to create a test user.

Comment: Verifying access as some user/profile/etc versus creating a user/profile/etc are separate concerns and should be separate test cases.